# Android, Chrome home screen shortcut with zxing

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, zxing

I’m using zxing with my webapp. I’ve created a chrome home screen shortcut. That allows me to open my webapp in chromes fullscreen mode. But when i try to scan barcode with zxing it returns me to normal mode of chrome browser without fullscreen. I understand that chrome homescreen shortcut launches an intent and opens my url with fullscreen but i don’t know how to use it with zxing ret value. Can anybody help me with that please? I need to open fullscreen browser after barcode is scanned.

Comment: See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356626/using-zxing-barcode-scanner-within-a-web-page/29931389#29931389